# How to do only one thing when I touch down the Button?

Tags: ios, swift

I can't describe it by only few sentences.

```
@IBOutlet weak var ClubIntro: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DetailButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func TouchDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    if DetailButton.titleLabel?.text == "收回"{
        ClubIntro.numberOfLines = 5
        DetailButton.titleLabel?.text = "展开"
    }
    else {
        ClubIntro.numberOfLines = 0
        DetailButton.titleLabel?.text = "收回"
    }
}
```

This is my code.I think it is easily to know what I want to do.

But this code didn't give a result I want.

The Button's text is "收回" default and the Label's numberoflines is 0

So, When I touch down the button.It will take the first IF sentence and change the button's title text to "展开" and the label's numberoflines to 5.

But because of the duration of touch down is so long, and then in the duration,the function TouchDown would be called again and then change the value back.

I have ever thought about the break sentence but it only can use in Loop.

So, how can I exit the function TouchDown when I finish the the first IF sentence?

Comment: you can use `TouchUpInside` instead of `TouchDown`.

Comment: it's quite strange..have you tried to CTRL-drag from your button to your code (from storyboard) and set connection as `Action` and put your code in the XCode created method?..

Comment: Yes I did, the function TouchDown it that method I create by storyboard.And its event is TouchUpInside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Problem:-**
You are doing it wrong! you should capture this event:-

```
UIControlEventTouchUpInside
```

A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

**Second  Problem:-**

I am late to detect it, it already answered before:-

You are not setting button title properly.

**This should be the way:-**   `DetailButton.setTitle("Button Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Comment: No, I have tried this kind of action at the first time.But the result is the same. And then I try the new Action TouchDown

Comment: Still not get your point! Have you tried to catch the action using UIControlEventTouchUpInside. If so update your code.

Comment: It is using UIContolEventTouchUpInside but the Action name is TouchDown.

Comment: Thanks for the second answer.It fixed the problem after I change that sentence to set title.

Answer (score 1):

create `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

```
@IBAction func TouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {

 let button = sender as UIButton
 if button.titleLabel?.text == "收回"{
     ClubIntro.numberOfLines = 5
     sender.setTitle("展开", forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
 }
 else {
     ClubIntro.numberOfLines = 0
     sender.setTitle("收回", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should set the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` as your control event flag so that button will detect what kinds of action should trigger the method. Besides, we are not sure whether that's your expected behavior, you should always look up the documentation in order to find your desire constant flag.

In code, you can set something like this in code or ctrl+drag from xib file then choose the `TouchUpInside`:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Because I can read Chinese and I think there is something wrong with your logic? You should understand that assigning 0 to `numberOfLines` is not actually putting it as 0 line. It means that it will auto-expand based on the actual content of the `UILabel`.

Comment: No,there is not wrong logic here.I have fixed the problem by using settitle method to change the button's title instead of assigning a string to the titlelabel directly.

Comment: Okay, as long as you know assigning 0 to `numberOfLines` is actually doing auto-resizing

Comment: Yes. So what my code do is when 展开 pressed then set numberoflines to 0 to autoresizing the label and then when 收回 is pressed it will set to 5 to let the label only have 5 lines